# How do I reverse search in String to get the index?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a string like this and would like to extract the link with `645w` resolution.

```
"//i.guim.co.uk/img/media/d126680aca92ff4251536f788b60233b5463af89/1585_707_3685_2210/3685.jpg?w=620&amp;q=85&amp;auto=format&amp;sharp=10&amp;s=ed7be5af3592322971e9e2276b5338f8 620w,

//i.guim.co.uk/img/media/d126680aca92ff4251536f788b60233b5463af89/1585_707_3685_2210/3685.jpg?w=700&amp;q=85&amp;auto=format&amp;sharp=10&amp;s=d49ff60c0c561cb2eee8d119acba62c5 700w,

//i.guim.co.uk/img/media/d126680aca92ff4251536f788b60233b5463af89/1585_707_3685_2210/3685.jpg?w=645&amp;q=85&amp;auto=format&amp;sharp=10&amp;s=19e251fb9bd21787e8364c091e4a89ce 645w,

//i.guim.co.uk/img/media/d126680aca92ff4251536f788b60233b5463af89/1585_707_3685_2210/3685.jpg?w=465&amp;q=85&amp;auto=format&amp;sharp=10&amp;s=fd5d66ed602638295446f28c4853744d 465w"
```

The position is not always the same, so I thought of using something like this:

```
if ' 645w' in src:
    index = src.find(" 645w")
    end_of_url = src[:index]
```

How can I now reverse search until I hit the beginning of the url and get the start-index of `//`?

Expected output is:

```
//i.guim.co.uk/img/media/d126680aca92ff4251536f788b60233b5463af89/1585_707_3685_2210/3685.jpg?w=645&q=85&auto=format&sharp=10&s=19e251fb9bd21787e8364c091e4a89ce
```

Comment: There is an `rfind()` in `str` instances.  Does it help you?

Comment: can it be converted into list

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: just print the previous line if the the match is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `string.rfind()` function, it searches the string in reverse order.

Example -

```
>>> if ' 645w' in src:
...     index = src.find(' 645w')
...     end_of_url = src[:index]
...     print(end_of_url[end_of_url.rfind('//'):])
...
//i.guim.co.uk/img/media/d126680aca92ff4251536f788b60233b5463af89/1585_707_3685_2210/3685.jpg?w=645&q=85&auto=format&sharp=10&s=19e251fb9bd21787e8364c091e4a89ce
```

Comment: While there are so many other proposed solutions that are working, this one here is closest to the question I had asked. Hence I'll accept his one.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn a `str` with `x[::-1]`.  If you search for your turned pattern in your turned string, you will find the occurrences in the order you want.  Just remember to convert the index values before using them.

Answer (score 0):

You can split by ',' and search 645w on each string.

Example :

```
  >>> links = "a 620w, b 700w, c 645w, d 456w";
  >>> linksArray = links.split(",");
  >>> for link in linksArray:
  ...     index = link.find("645w");
  ...     if index > -1:
  ...         print(link[:index]);
  // out : " c "
```

You need to adapt a little bit more, but I prefer keep things friendly than reverse search and cut.

Comment: I liked your solution, kinda adopted it in some form, but you seem to be a Javascript developer right? Semicolons at the end and using wrong casing ;)

Comment: Thank you, I am a C/C++ developer then semicolon & camelize is important for me. :P

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a list of URLs that contain `645w`

```
[url[:url.find(' 645w')] for url in src.split(', ') if ' 645w' in url]
```

Which in this case evaluates to:

```
['//i.guim.co.uk/img/media/d126680aca92ff4251536f788b60233b5463af89/1585_707_3685_2210/3685.jpg?w=645&q=85&auto=format&sharp=10&s=19e251fb9bd21787e8364c091e4a89ce']
```

Comment: Interesting solution. Although the `  645w` should be cut at the end, as its not part of the link. But I see your point.

Answer (score 0):

```
s  = "//i.guim.co.uk/img/media/d126680aca92ff4251536f788b60233b5463af89/1585_707_3685_2210/3685.jpg?w=620&q=85&auto=format&sharp=10&s=ed7be5af3592322971e9e2276b5338f8 620w, //i.guim.co.uk/img/media/d126680aca92ff4251536f788b60233b5463af89/1585_707_3685_2210/3685.jpg?w=700&q=85&auto=format&sharp=10&s=d49ff60c0c561cb2eee8d119acba62c5 700w, //i.guim.co.uk/img/media/d126680aca92ff4251536f788b60233b5463af89/1585_707_3685_2210/3685.jpg?w=645&q=85&auto=format&sharp=10&s=19e251fb9bd21787e8364c091e4a89ce 645w, //i.guim.co.uk/img/media/d126680aca92ff4251536f788b60233b5463af89/1585_707_3685_2210/3685.jpg?w=465&q=85&auto=format&sharp=10&s=fd5d66ed602638295446f28c4853744d 465w"


print([url.strip(" 645w") for url in s.split(",") if url.endswith("645w")])
['//i.guim.co.uk/img/media/d126680aca92ff4251536f788b60233b5463af89/1585_707_3685_2210/3685.jpg?w=645&q=85&auto=format&sharp=10&s=19e251fb9bd21787e8364c091e4a89ce']
```